# Markdown Editor Toolbar missing?

Tags: bug, editor

Recently, *sometimes,* whenever I edit / create, a post the markdown buttons / preview seem to be missing:

[image]

In the console. `Markdown` and `StackExchange.MarkdownEditor` are both undefined. I don't see a script tag with `wmd.en.js` at all either so maybe something's not loading? Sometimes refreshing fixes it, which makes it even more weird.

Comment: In which browser? Any corporate(dodgy ISP's) network devices in your network?

Comment: @rene Safari 9.0.1, no firewalls at all in my network.

Comment: I always had this problem when using Add Another Answer or similar (where `alert()` was called before the answer box was shown) when using Safari 9.0.1, my daily browser. I'd use another answer box and copy-paste my answer in to the box with the missing editor. I'm unable to reproduce the bug in Safari 9.1.

Comment: Hard page refresh in Firefox: Ctrl + F5